# Close reasons on MSO still include MSE text

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, mso-mse-split

The following close reason on Meta Stackoverflow needs rewriting now that Meta StackExchange has ascended to a higher astral plane:

> **off-topic because...** This question does not appear to be about Stack Overflow or the software that powers the Stack Exchange network, within the scope defined in the help center.

[image: close reasons]

Comment: No, you can still report problems on the software that powers the Stack Exchange network (which includes Stack Overflow), right here. **This is not an error**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If an issue effects the site you normally use, reporting in on the child meta of that site is fine.

That is - if you see something that is an issue on Stack Overflow, posting it on Meta Stack Overflow is **fine**, even if it effecting the whole network.

Therefore - the close reason is valid.